# python foreach loop and dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting my feet wet with python. I have an issue. I have one array and one dictionary and I am trying to match the data between them. I am coming form php background so I may get the terminology wrong while I try to learn python. So here we go.

```
product = [{'id': 57L, 'product_name': '3-Piece Reversible Bonded Leather Match Sofa Set in Cream'}, {'id': 58L, 'product_name': '3-Piece Sage Microfiber Sectional Sofa Set with Faux Leather Ottoman'}, {'id': 663L, 'product_name': 'Recycled Plastic Adirondack Tete-a-tete'}, {'id': 717L, 'product_name': 'Designer 20-Bottle Wine Cabinet'}]
```

then I am loading a json file into dictionary like this

```
productsChecked = json.loads(open('/Library/WebServer/Documents/scrapper/test2.json').read())
```

and looping over productsChecked gives me something like this if I do print

```
{u'price': u'$399.00', u'product_name': u'Glendale Brown PU Leather Ottoman with Pull-out Guest Bed', u'availability': u'In Stock'}
```

so I have now this

```
productsChecked = json.loads(open('/Library/WebServer/Documents/scrapper/test2.json').read())
for key, value in enumerate(productsChecked):
    for v in value.iteritems():
        print v
```

so that gives me this

```
(u'price', u'$93.00')
(u'product_name', u'Espresso Hand-Woven Cane Panel 2-Door Wall-Hanging Bathroom Cabinet')
(u'availability', u'In Stock')
```

I am not sure what that means...I wanted to get the product_name from above and wanted to compare it with product_name from the first product array and if the product_name from the json/dictionary matched the product_name from product array then I wanted to print out product_name matched but now I am not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`productsChecked` is just a list of dictionaries, so you can access the `product_name` key *directly*:

```
productsChecked = json.load(open('/Library/WebServer/Documents/scrapper/test2.json'))

print productsChecked[0]['product_name']
```

You can check if any item in `products` matches with `any()`:

```
for check_product in productsChecked:
    if any(p['product_name'] == check_product['product_name'] for p in product):
        # match!
```

or you can search for the matching product with a loop:

```
for check_product in productsChecked:
    for prod in product:
        if prod['product_name'] == check_product['product_name']:
            print 'Match:', prod
```

which matches multiple `product` entries *and* gives you the matching dictionary.

This does all get inefficient fast; you are looping over both lists, creating N*M loops. You can reduce that by turning your initial `product` list into a dictionary for fast O(1) constant time lookups:

```
products_map = {p['product_name']: p for p in product}
```

This does assume that product names are unique.

Now you can just look up the product name directly:

```
for check_product in productsChecked:
    if check_product['product_name'] in products_map:
        # the named product is in our map
```

Comment: when I ran the above code, I get this error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updateDBwithFastFurnishing.py", line 22, in <module>
    if prod['product_name'] == productsChecked['product_name']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Indeed, I did not realize you have a *list* of dictionaries; not just one. Did you want to match *every* product entry in that list?

Comment: When you define `productsChecked`, put a `[0]` at the end to grab the dictionary out of the list structure, and I think the rest will work: `productsChecked = json.load(open('/Library/WebServer/Documents/scrapper/test2.json'))[0]`

Comment: And what if the OP wants to process all entries in the JSON file?

Comment: I want to process all the entries of the json file

Comment: ALso I have the need to match every product